# How to configure locale based date format support in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, datetime-format

Does someone had this problem:

I need to configure spring to recognize locale based date and number format, i.e. the following user behavior should be valid:

1. User select language to `EN`, then the number format `1.23` should be valid, spring mvc will accept this format and no valid error triggered. User can also change the date with date format `MM/dd/yyyy` and no valid error raised, user can post this form.
2. User select language to `DE`, then the number format `1,23` should bevalid, spring mvc will accept this format and no valid error triggered. User can also change the date with date format `dd.MM.yyyy` and no valid error triggerd. User can post this form.

I'v tried to use `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="#{messageSource['date_format']}")`,(I have date_format defined in messages_(locale).properties) but seems spring doesn't support this yet, see [JIRA ISSUE](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8654)

Does someone has the similar problem and got a solution.

Does it help to write my own converter, and register it in `org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`? I need some kind of request based converter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since nobody answers my question, I just post one of my solution to solve this problem, it could help others:

1. I had a request scoped bean, which resolves locale using: `RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request);` request can be autowired to the request scoped class(NOTICE, it works only with field injection, not with construction or setter). In this class I get locale based date/number format.
2. In my controller (we have actually a abstractController). I have code like this:

   ```
   @InitBinder
   public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
       binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new LocalizedDateEditor(formatHelper));
   }
   ```

`formatHelper` is the request scoped bean. `LocalizedDateEditor` looks like this:

```
public class LocalizedDateEditor extends CustomDateEditor {

    public LocalizedDateEditor(FormatHelper formatHelper) {
        super(new SimpleDateFormat(formatHelper.getDefaultDateFormat()), true);
    }
}
```

It just tell spring to use my dateFormat.

That's all.

Comment: I really appreciate your question and especially your own answer. It was a great help to me. Thank you so much my friend!